syncfusion_flutter_datepicker not showing month text
I am using syncfusion_flutter_datepicker to get the date range. but it seems that the month display is not showing. the name of each month is not showing, besides when selecting a month the text is not showing.


SfDateRangePicker(
  onSelectionChanged: ((args) {
    setState(() {
      if (args.value is PickerDateRange) {
        startDate = args.value.startDate;
        filterDateStart = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(args.value.startDate);
        filterDateStartText = DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy').format(args.value.startDate);

        endDate = args.value.endDate ?? args.value.startDate;
        filterDateEnd = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(args.value.endDate ?? args.value.startDate);
        filterDateEndText = DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy').format(args.value.endDate ?? args.value.startDate);

        getOrderHistoryPaginate(page: currentPage, status: filterStatus, startDate: filterDateStart, endDate: filterDateEnd);
      }
    });
  }),
  view: DateRangePickerView.month,
  selectionMode: DateRangePickerSelectionMode.range,
  initialSelectedRange: PickerDateRange(
    startDate, endDate),
)

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3737], locale en-ID)
[✓] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.11)
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.91.0)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] Network resources
syncfusion_flutter_datepicker: ^22.2.12

Just try to change the background color of date picker and see if there is any text is there or not.

@AbhishekPatel I have tried it, but it doesn't work the month name doesn't show. But when I click on that position in img1, it will redirect to img2.

place your full widget code here

Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are not open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

By default, the app's color scheme has mapped to the SfDateRangePicker. I suspect that you have modified the default theme data affecting the SfDateRangePickerTheme. To resolve this issue, I recommend using the SfDateRangePickerTheme to customize the theme. I have shared a user guide and documentation for the SfDateRangePickerTheme, along with a live sample that includes the default theme data, for your reference.
UG  Link: https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_core/latest/theme/SfDateRangePickerTheme-class.html
Live sample: https://flutter.syncfusion.com/#/date-range-picker/getting-started
If you are still facing any issue, please provide a reproduce sample. This will be more helpful to provide a solution sooner.
